# How can I print a sorted array using a standard for loop in PHP? (Not a foreach loop)

Tags: php, for-loop

I was able to sort my array using the asort function, and i know that it's working, as I've used vardump to check. My issue is printing just the elements in the sorted array using a for loop.

```
        $month = array ('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July','August','September', 'October', 'November', 'December');

        asort($month);

        for ($i=0; $i < count($month); $i++) { 
                echo $month[$i];
                echo "<br>\n";
            }
```

Comment: whenever i run the script above, I am met with an output of the original array.

Comment: Do a `print_r($month)` and you should see why your loop prints in the original order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sort` rather than `asort`.

`asort` maintains the relationship between keys and values, but in this case, you're iterating the keys in order, so you'll get the values in order, even though the array really is sorted.

If you `var_dump($month)` after using `asort`, you'll see:

```
array(12) {
  [3]  => string(5) "April"
  [7]  => string(6) "August"
  [11] => string(8) "December"
  [1]  => string(8) "February"
  [0]  => string(7) "January"
  [6]  => string(4) "July"
  [5]  => string(4) "June"
  [2]  => string(5) "March"
  [4]  => string(3) "May"
  [10] => string(8) "November"
  [9]  => string(7) "October"
  [8]  => string(9) "September"
}
```

The `0` index still refers to January, for example, even though it's no longer the first element.

[`sort` assigns new keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php#refsect1-function.sort-notes), so your `for` loop will work properly.

Comment: okay this makes a lot of sense, thank you for the detailed explanation!